# How to pass runtime parameter (params) in Selenium Side runner?

Tags: selenium

How to pass runtime parameter (params) in Selenium Side runner?
I want to execute the Side file from command prompt and also pass various urls and user names as parameters to run. i tried selenium-side-runner --params "a='example-value'", it didn't work.

Comment: Post your code please